# Maybe difference of two Maybe Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to compute the difference of two `elemIndex` values for a list.

```hs
colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"]

ib = elemIndex "blue" colours
-- Just 0

iy = elemIndex "yellow" colours
-- Just 3

-- the following obviously does not work
distance = abs $ ib - iy
```

I've tried different ways to use the bind operator `>>=` but no success so far. Ideally, I'd want an expression that returns a `Just` of the difference between the two Ints if both are `Just`, or `Nothing` if at least one of them is `Nothing`.

Example:

```hs
mydistancefunction (Just 0) (Just 3)
-- Just 3

mydistancefunction (Just 1) (Just 2)
-- Just 1

mydistancefunction (Just 3) (Nothing)
-- Nothing
```

Comment: Are you aware of `liftA2`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I wasn't — but now, thanks to you I am.

Comment: You don't need a monad doing this but if you would write a composition by hand it'd look like `ib >>= \b -> iy >>= \y -> Just $ b - y`. The important property is that it is nested even though the parenthesis are implicit in Haskell.

Comment: that's `ib >>= (\b -> iy >>= (\y -> (Just $ b - y)))` with parens explicitly written out. but easiest is to write `do` code, `do { b <- ib ; y <- iy ; return (b - y) }`. it *is* equivalent to `liftA2 (-) ib iy`. `liftM2`, actually. so, easiest just to write `do` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, [`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) will lift a binary function `distance :: Num a => a -> a -> a` to work with `Maybe` values because [`Maybe` is an applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-992).

```
myDistance :: Num a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
myDistance = liftA2 distance
  where
    distance x y = abs $ x - y
```

Comment: In addition to the fixed-arity `liftA2` & `liftA3` for simple cases, it’s also very common to write this kind of thing inline with the `f <$> x1 <*> … <*> xN` pattern of functor & applicative operators. Using the example from the question, that’d be: `distance = abs <$> ((-) <$> ib <*> iy)`.